# Align Border CSS

Tags: html, css, alignment, border

I am quite confused with the layout I got. How do I align border on bottom of the text. Below is an image of the layout and my html ..

[IMAGE OF THE LAYOUT](https://d1ro8r1rbfn3jf.cloudfront.net/ms_65043/IhDN71JSNsfYSpgWg9ynCnHtHpnd7v/Adobe%2BCreative%2BCloud%2B-%2BGoogle%2BChrome%2B2015-09-28%2B06.03.44.png?Expires=1443489011&Signature=M~VKlbCviZu9bCO8NlyT63DdOKIpoCvr7HfxHbeq10-wDSYmmWNthIx2~~EDeKugm-qbmllf0DRvMiX7i2eAcg5TEq2WTRUhkau2eMsSMktHz5mLR0khgrwqkbxuVzrkRUAaFHcN65Ub1Y7sbyzrwRSDImEalghHVko32S86jOPSPFDIykl9clYikJrQGbYb~4dZhV9e-FmySL2AVumQzI2CzYb6V1IRT9QxeQge2GmB-EfZLjOlhyqvnk-dooorFa2ZizZIodkDzC56SC45~xA13wdFW9Pe5hxO-bIJz5cKk4W52CJu5RnqxqufJ~mvd0BfAbcZX~ZadMMvfx6WTQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJHEJJBIZWFB73RSA)

**HTML**

```
<div class="submission-box-wrapper">
    <div class="submission-box-inner">
        <h5>ON-CAMERA, AGES 3 &amp; UP:</h5>

        <h6>For Submissions to the Atlanta Office:</h6>
        <p>J Pervis Talent Agency
        949 Image Avenue, Suite C
        Atlanta, GA 30318</p>

        <h6>For Submission to the Louisiana Office:</h6>
        <p>J Pervis Talent Agency
        PO Box 3215
        Baton Rouge, LA 70821</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

**Pending CSS**

```
.submission-box-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

.submission-box-inner {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(226, 226, 226);
    width: 100%;
}

.submission-box-inner h5 {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    color:  #dcab06;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-align: left;
}

.submission-box-inner h6 {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-weight: 800;
    line-height: 30px;
    text-align: left;
 }

.submission-box-inner p {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    color:  #000000;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 20px;
    text-align: left;
 }
```

Can someone please help me out a bit here ..

Thanks ..

Comment: Post your CSS too...

Comment: @nevermind done mate ..

Comment: The [code in your question](http://jsfiddle.net/hut46hxm/) doesn't match your image, you may need to isolate and reproduce the issue.

Comment: @apaul34208 are you talking about the css or the html?

Comment: Wait... Is the image  what you have now or what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I think my way is not the best but still do what you want so why you not give it a chance.
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/j56fokkh/)
**New CSS**

```
.submission-box-inner {
    position: relative;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(226, 226, 226);
    width: 100%;
    top:10px;
}
.submission-box-inner h5 {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    color: #DCAB06;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 22px;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 0 5px;
}
```